How to update the timestamp parameter for CSS files?
I have worked on a CSS file of a TYPO3 11.5 website directly on the web server. How can I update the timestamp parameter on the CSS file main.css?1715067859  to refresh browser cache? I don't have a CLI, but admin access to the back-end.

If you use "normal" TYPO3 means for bundling your CSS (i.e. via TypoScript configuration) it should be sufficient for you to clear the General + Frontend Cache to get the fresh timestamp.
If however you created the CSS with outside tooling (i.e. gulp/grunt/vite) you'll need to execute a new deployment on the server, that can't be done within TYPO3 backend.

Unfortunately, deleting the general and frontend cache does not help. Yes it's a static CSS file generated with outside tooling. Is there a way to deactivate these parameters in the backend?

Is the actual CSS file saved with or without a "?17xxxx" timestamp? If the file is just called "main.css" you would need to "touch" the file on the Shell/SSH/FTP level to update the filetime modification, which is used for the stamp in some configs. You can't do that from within the TYPO3 backend though, but need access at filesystem level (or extensions/code that allow file editing within the backend)

What is the timestamp-parameter for?
It's to inform your browser, that it needs to reload the CSS file, after you edited something.
If the CSS file is generated in TYPO3 it can use another timestamp. if the file is generated outside of TYPO3 it's your responsibility to void the browser cache for the CSS file.
In TYPO3 you can declare the CSS file as external so TYPO3 does not care and generates no timestamp. Then you need to flush the browser cache after each CSS change.
